# Why does this LinqPad program produce different results on the second run?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am developing a simple PID controller in LinqPad:

## The PID Class

```cs
class PidController
{
    public float Proportional { get; set; }
    public float Integral { get; set; }
    public float Derivative { get; set; }
    public float SetPoint { get; set; }
    public float Kp { get; set; }
    public float Ki { get; set; }
    public float Kd { get; set; }

    float _lastError;
    DateTime _lastTime = DateTime.Now;

    public PidController(float kp, float ki, float kd)
    {
        Kp = kp; Ki = ki; Kd = kd;
    }

    public float GetControlValue(float actual)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        var deltaTime = (float)(currentTime - _lastTime).TotalSeconds;
        var error = SetPoint - actual;

        Proportional = error;
        Integral = Integral + error * deltaTime;
        Derivative = (error - _lastError) / deltaTime;

        _lastError = error;

        return Kp * Proportional + Ki * Integral + Kd * Derivative;
    }
}
```

For testing and tuning, the controller will control this simple process:

### The Controlled Process

```cs
class SimpleProcess
{
    private DateTime _lastTime = DateTime.Now;
    private float _output;

    public float Output { get { UpdateOutput(); return _output; }}
    public float Input { get; set; }

    private void UpdateOutput()
    {
        var deltaTime = (float)(DateTime.Now - _lastTime).TotalSeconds;
        _output += Input * deltaTime;
    }
}
```

...using this main loop:

### The Main Program Loop

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pid = new PidController(1f, 0f, 0f) { SetPoint = 100f };
    var proc = new SimpleProcess();

    // pid.Dump();
    // proc.Dump();

    var values = new List<ProcessValue>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        var actual = proc.Output;
        var controlValue = pid.GetControlValue(actual);
        proc.Input = controlValue;

        var value = new ProcessValue
        {
            index = i,
            timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("ss.fff"),
            p = pid.Proportional,
            i = pid.Integral,
            d = pid.Derivative,
            input = controlValue,
            output = actual
        };

        values.Add(value);

        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    values.Dump();
}

public class ProcessValue
{
    public int index;
    public string timestamp;
    public float p, i, d, input, output;
}
```

Everything works as expected on the first run:

```
index  timestamp  p      i       d         input output
0      53.309     100    0.46    21490.59  100   0 
1      53.411     89.69  10.06  -96.27     89.69 10.30 
etc...
```

However, I started getting unexpected results on the second and subsequent runs after I commented out the line `proc.Dump()`:

```
index  timestamp  p    i    d    input  output 
0      10.199     100  0    ∞    NaN    0 
1      10.299     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN 
2      10.399     NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN 
etc...
```

**Why is the second run (and subsequent runs) returning different results in my case?**

Any of the following actions will cause the next run to succeed:

- modify the code (even just adding/removing a single whitespace)
- press [CTRL]+[SHIFT]+[F5]

The following makes the code run correctly every time:

- uncomment the line `proc.Dump()`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088970/506174) mentions that static variables will be cached between runs, but I have no static variables. I suspect the problem *is* related to the *Application Domain Caching* feature in LinqPad, but I'm trying to understand why I'm affected by this.

## Update

StriplingWarrior's answer is correct, my first derivative calculation resulted in Infinity when they system was performing well (i.e. after LinqPad had cached the first run), causing all subsequent calculations to fail. Modifying my program in any way was invalidating this cache and caused the deltaTime to be large enough to avoid the error again on the next run.

Since a derivative term makes no sense on the first interval, I decided to handle this by simply ignoring it:

```
var p = Kp * Proportional;
var i = Ki * Integral;
var d = float.IsInfinity(Derivative) ? 0 : Kd * Derivative;

return p + i + d;
```

Comment: What is `PidController.ProcessValue`? That doesn't appear in your posted code.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior it's just a POCO to hold the values for the list of results that I `Dump()` at the end - it's poorly named and in the wrong spot... but just there for debugging at the moment. I've added it back in to the code above.

Comment: Well, I ran this in VS and I wasn't able to reproduce your second scenario. Anyway, if `d` is infinite, it must be because `deltaTime` is zero. Which means that the time between `pid = new PidController` and `pid.GetControlValue` is almost zero. If you call those `Dump` methods, you are clearly adding some time there. Even building in Release mode and executing from outside VS, it still takes like 1 ms between those two lines.
BTW, rather than `_lastTime` that variable should be called something like `CreationTime`. Are you using CleanCode? Because I don't have that `List.Dump` method.

Comment: It's a little hard to follow, but I notice you've got a bunch of stuff in here based on subtracting `DateTime.Now` values from one another. My first impression would be that initialization and loading of classes might make some things take just a little bit longer on the first run, while the app is not loaded into memory, and that might be making the differences between DateTimes give you more meaningful-looking values.

Comment: @Andrew `Dump` is a method that LinqPad includes to easily output to the console.

Comment: I would agree with @StriplingWarrior. deltaTime must be returning zero and the divide by zero is causing the Nan's. You could try setting `Util.NewProcess = true;` to disable the Application Domain Caching

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you're on to something - adding a `Thread.Sleep(100)` right after initializing `var proc = ...` causes it to work as expected... I'll look more closely at the time calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test what Andrew theorizes in your comments above, by changing the first part of your main method thusly:

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
var pid = new PidController(1f, 0f, 0f) { SetPoint = 100f };
var proc = new SimpleProcess();

// pid.Dump();
// proc.Dump();

var values = new List<ProcessValue>();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    var actual = proc.Output;
    var controlValue = pid.GetControlValue(actual);
    if(sw.IsRunning){
        sw.Stop();
        sw.ElapsedTicks.Dump();
    }
```

Running on my machine, I can see that the first run takes 10,000+ ticks, whereas the second run takes only 20 ticks. I'm guessing this makes your calculations based on differences in DateTime.Now have very small delta values, and yield the differences you're seeing.

Comment: You are correct - the derivative calculation resulted in NaN due to the extremely small time difference, which caused the resulting sum to be NaN as well.